Can't connect to MongoDB atlas using Mongoose 8.9.1
My MongoDB URI looks like this
mongodb+srv://<db_admin>:<db_password>@maincluster.expmq.mongodb.net/<db_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=MainCluster

I have a express application that tries to connect to MongoDB atlas using mongoose


require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

const DB = process.env.DB_URI
    .replace('<db_admin>', process.env.DB_ADMIN_USERNAME)
    .replace('<db_password>', process.env.DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD)
    .replace('<db_name>', process.env.DB_NAME);

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(DB);
        console.log('Database connected successfully');
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(`Error connecting to database! Closing Connection!!`);
        console.error(`ERROR ===> ${err}`);
        mongoose.connection.close();
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

connectDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Backend running`);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});



When I run my app I keep getting this error
 Error connecting to database! Closing Connection!!
 ERROR ===> Error: querySrv EBADNAME _mongodb._tcp.3!

Things that you should know

Allowed network access from all IP's (0.0.0.0/0)
Changing network provider using mobile hotspot, ethernet, wifi
Changing IPv4 DNS to google (8.8.8.8) alternate DNS (8.8.4.4)
Node version 22.12.0
Mongoose version 8.9.2
Express version 4.21.2

console.log(err.stack) gives this response
Error: querySrv EBADNAME _mongodb._tcp.3!
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:293:17)

This highlights that it might be a DNS issue but how do I resolve this?

Are you able to ping the db domain? Did you try connecting to it via MongoDB Compass or any other db client?

@PrerakSola Nevermind I found the issue, I had an @ in the password and that is why it was not working.
